# Trying to understand Rails ajax js code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ive been trying to work out how to prepend a comment once its been created via Ajax, I added remote true to the form. Inserted the block in the controller but then it got the js file where i prepended the new comment. I couldn't figure it out. I came across this code on SO and quickly gave it a shot and it worked. But i cant work out why/how?

This is the code: JS file,

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @message) %>").prependTo(".view-messages");
```

Here is the div to which it is prepended

```
<div class="view-messages">
  <%= nested_messages @messages.arrange(:order => :created_at) %>
</div>
```

Its this line here `$("<%= escape_javascript(render @message) %>")` Ive tried debugging it but cant,

What is that printing out, is it one of these rails magic things or am i being stupid?

Although it works i like to know why and how so if anyone can help me out me id be grateful.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
$("<div class=\"body body-144\">\n  <span class=\"tip tip-left\"><\/span>\n  <div class=\"message font-medium\">\n    ellll <br />\n  <\/div>\n  <div class=\"flerowspb\">\n    <span class=\"font-small\">\n      <a href=\"/profiles/122\">Nyall2911(28)<\/a>\n      <\/span>\n      <span class=\"font-small\">\n        <a href=\"/messages/new?entry_id=344&amp;parent_id=144\">Reply<\/a>\n      <a rel=\"nofollow\" data-method=\"delete\" href=\"/messages/144\">| Delete<\/a>\n    <\/span>\n  <\/div>\n<\/div>\n")
```

This is what its rendering, So i suppose my question is, how is rails getting all of the HTML from my comment partial by just calling `(render @message)`

Comment: At a glance, it looks like it's prepending whatever's stored in *@message* to a JS `.view-messages` attribute or perhaps calling it on all the matching CSS classes in the DOM. Are you using jQuery? Without knowing the actual content of what's being rendered, it's hard to say what's really going on, so turn on debugging and let us know what's being rendered from *@message*.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Ive updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `escape_javascript` method: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/55f9b8129a50206513264824abb44088230793c2/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb#L25

Per the comment below the method, it looks like it replaces a few unsafe characters and returns raw HTML using the `html_safe` method. `jQuery` then prepends that raw HTML to your div.